# How to debug async/await in visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, async-await, visual-studio-code

I want to debug js file that includes async/await in visual studio code,but it reminds me that vscode doesn't support it. What can I do to make vscode support async/await?

Comment: `async/await` is not part of ES7.

Comment: I'd recommend just using the browser's debugger. (Chrome is great) It typically is a smoother experience and you're debugging the actual file being used.

Answer (score 20):

As now, in 2019, latest VSCode supporting async/await debug, just would like to share solution to prevent vscode to "Step into" (by f11) into async/await method through the "**async_hooks.js**" and "**inspector_async_hook.js**" files during debug nodejs applications.

Howto :

1) press ctrl+p in vscode and type ">launch", select "open launch.json"

2) after opening "launch.json", just add to configuration section :

```
"skipFiles": [
    "inspector_async_hook.js",
    "async_hooks.js"
  ]
```

or some more generic version :

```
"skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"]
```

So you final json should looks something like here:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\index.js",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"]
    }
  ]
}
```

After these steps you can see your real async method after pressing F11 in debug mode.

Comment: is it still relevant in 2022?

Answer (score 7):

Currently you can use async/await  in Node.js 7 or latest using --harmony flag, you can configure your vscode debugger (launch.json) in the following way to run and debug async/await Nodejs code.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Node 7 Async/Await",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--harmony",
                "--no-deprecation"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Process",
            "port": 5858
        }
    ]
}
```

You must change the program by your startup script file.

Comment: Running debugger with  this with ES6/ES7 doesn't seem to work for me. It can't seem to debug a ES6/ES7 code. Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you find these configuration could you please share documentation link

Answer (score 4):

I had major performance issues with **VS Code** debugging a **Node** project with **TypeScript** was unusable, so I found that changing the [`protocol=='inspector'`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_supported-nodelike-runtimes) and targeting `es2017` allowed a fast and reliable debugging experience. Here is the config I used...

#### launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/lib/main.js",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--harmony",
                "--no-deprecation"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/lib/**/*.js"
            ],
             "skipFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/**/*.js"
            ],
            "smartStep": true
        }
    ]
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017", 
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true, 
    "sourceMap": true,   
    "outDir": "lib",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true  
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions seems to mention the issue I had.

I am using `jest` with `typescript` (`ts-jest`). Whenever I tried to step into the `awaitable` method -  the debugger would skip through the method and end up on a closing bracket, hence skipping the method entirely. (I was still able to step into the code by placing a debug point inside the method, but it is inconvenient to say the least)

Given the config:

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",

  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsconfig: "tsconfig.testing.jest.json"
    },
  },
}
```

The solution for me was updrading the `target` in `tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "ES2017",
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",

    //
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue"
  ],
  "exclude": ["dist", "node_modules"]
}
```

It was targeting `ES2015` so I changed it to `ES2017`. I think under the hood the typescript compiler was producing a code that vscode didn't know how to deal with and the latest `ES` basically allows compiling `async`/`awaits` as-is.

p.s. I don't know if this is relevant at this point but I tried a bunch of solutions and just to make sure - if the problem is not resolved for you with the tip from above - try some of the config options from below :)

```
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",

  automock: false,

  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsconfig: "tsconfig.testing.jest.json",
    },
  },

  rootDir: "./",
  modulePaths: ["<rootDir>"],

  moduleNameMapper: {
    "#(.*)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/$1",
  },

  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules"],

  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
  },

  testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",

  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],

  roots: [
    //"<rootDir>",
    "./tests",
  ],
```

this config is very specific to `ts` tests, so keep that in mind

Answer (score -2):

until we have VSCode's support on that subject,
you can try putting your results into a var like this:

```
var results = async function();
```

and check the value in results

Answer (score -3):

You can use the Node.js `--inspect` option to debug your code in Chrome. Just like this:

```
# node --inspect app/app.js
```

And open the Chrome: `chrome://inspect`. That's so cool.
You can specify in [this doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/inspector.html).