# How to call async functions from VSCode debugger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, async-await

If I drop into the VSCode debugger in some javascript code and call an asynchronous function with await it just returns a promise. How can I resolve the promise within the debugger so I can see what the result is?

For example, if I define a function like so:

```
const doAsyncThing = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(5)
        }, 1000)
    })
}

(async function() {
    const result = await doAsyncThing()
    console.log(`result is ${result}`)
    debugger
})()
```

Then this happens when I call it in the debugger:

```
result is 5
> result
5
> await doAsyncThing()
Promise {<pending>}
> const result2 = await doAsyncThing()
Promise {<pending>}
> result2
Uncaught ReferenceError: result2 is not defined
> doAsyncThing().then(r => console.log(r))
Promise {<pending>}
> await doAsyncThing().then(r => console.log(r))
Promise {<pending>}
```

How can I make it resolve the promise and get me the result within the debugger?

This is not a duplicate of [How to debug async/await in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771097/how-to-debug-async-await-in-visual-studio-code) That question appears to be asking how to place a breakpoint within an asynchronous function, while I am trying to actually execute the function from the debugger. I previously asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64996504/how-to-execute-async-functions-in-vscode-debugger) but it was closed (incorrectly I believe) as a duplicate. I added additional context here to help clarify the difference.

Comment: instead of `const result = await doAsyncThing()` you could try `doAsyncThing().then(result => ...)`

Comment: i'm not sure what to do in the `...` section though, apart from console.logging something, or maybe assigning the result to a global variable

Comment: also, if you've hit a breakpoint and you're trying to get access to `result` while in a breakpoint... i'm not actually sure that's even possible really

Comment: @TKoL Thanks, I did exactly what you suggested in the code example above and used console.log but it still did not log the result.

Answer (score 1):

When you using `debugger`, it also pauses app.

Best way to know result of function is `doAsyncThing().then(console.log)`, but function will not be executed until you press `F5` key (Continue).

While app is not paused, you can use debug console to call async functions and *this will work*. Best way to check this is next code:

```
const doAsyncThing = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(5)
      }, 1000)
  })
}

global.testFn = doAsyncThing;

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
});
```

And use next command in debug console: `global.testFn().then(console.log)`

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbofZ.png)

Note, that I'm using global, because debug console don't have context of file until you paused app. But you can use modules by `require`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var model = mongoose.model('Users');
model.findOne().then(console.log).catch(console.warn);
```

Comment: I was trying to set a breakpoint in so that my async function was in scope. Making it global and calling it while not paused didn't occur to me. ty

Comment: But I still had to assign the global interactively from a break point

Comment: Could you please make screenshot?